# Enqueuing C# Queues

Tags: c#, queue, nullreferenceexception

I'm making a fighting game, and I am trying to keep a queue of moves input by the player. For some reason, I am unable to add my strings to the queue.

```
moverecorder.Enqueue(instructions);
```

"instructions" is a three-character string. whenever this runs, I get the error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object

I've tried replacing 'instructions' with a string, but the error persists.

How do I Enqueue a string?

Comment: Are you sure moverecorder is not null?

Comment: Did you create the instance of queue before adding items into it?

Comment: Thanks guys :) that was correct. I didn't think I had to initialize it like that, because I was under the impression that queues were able to hole multiple data types.

Comment: If multiple threads are deqeueing the queue at the same time its being queued you can get this exception too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look at the [definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t249c2y7.aspx) for Queue.Enqueue you will see that the value passed to the queue can be null. So your error is not comming from the argument that you're passing.

Probably your `moverecorder` is null.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you need `moverecorder = new Queue<string>();` somewhere before you try to enqueue.